# WPF DataGrid cell value changed event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a setup that looks like this:

```
// myDG is a DataGrid whose columns are DataGridTextColumn
ObservableCollection<MyItem> myOC;
// myOC is populated with some new MyItem
myDG.ItemsSource = myOC;
```

where `MyItem` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. What's the way to properly catch when the *user* inputs a value into a cell?

I've tried catching `PropertyChanged` on the `MyItem`s, but I also update the values periodically in the background (the idea is that when the user manually edits the value, a flag is triggered that tells the periodic calculation to avoid overwriting the manually entered data). So `PropertyChanged` catches everything, including the periodic updates, which I don't want. I suppose it's possible to make this work (by setting a flag when I do the periodic calculation, then checking for absence of flag on the PropertyChanged event handler -- but I want to know if there's a simpler solution.)

I've tried catching `myDG.CurrentCellChanged` but that's triggered every time the user changes the cell selection, not specifically when they edit cell contents.

Edit: Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDG" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,182,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="329" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Prop1}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Prop2}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the `MyItem` implementation (uses [Fody/PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)):

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public MyItem()
    {
        Prop1 = Prop2 = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your XAML implementation.

Comment: Just change setter method?

Comment: Have you looked at a list of events exposed by DataGrid ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The solution was to catch the `CellEditEnding` event.

```
// In initialization
myDG.CellEditEnding += myDG_CellEditEnding;

void myDG_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var column = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
        if (column != null)
        {
            var bindingPath = (column.Binding as Binding).Path.Path;
            if (bindingPath == "Col2")
            {
                int rowIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
                var el = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
                // rowIndex has the row index
                // bindingPath has the column's binding
                // el.Text has the new, user-entered value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SUB-HDR for delete you can     if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                MyItemList.Remove((MyItem)myDG.SelectedItem);
            }

Comment: Did you put this code in your .xaml.cs or in your viewmodel, because for me if it's not in .xaml.cs it says it doesn't find the function...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by Using **CellEditEnding**  event and another thing is  in DataGridTextColumn have to add some attributes like below :-

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDG" CellEditEnding="myDG_CellEditEnding"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,182,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="329" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Prop1}" 
 IsReadOnly="True"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dataGridTextColumn"Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Prop2,  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

IN C#

```
 private void myDG_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) {
            string prop1 = (e.Row.Item as DataRowView).Row[1].ToString();
        }
```